Differences in Compilation Results Between GCC and Clang
I encountered a situation where my C code compiles successfully with GCC but generates errors when compiled with Clang.
Here is my C code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define release_ptr(ptr) do { free(ptr); ptr = NULL; } while (0)

int test(int type)
{
  switch (type) {
  case 0:
    puts("zero");
    return 0;
  case 1: // here's the problem
    char* temp = calloc(sizeof(char), 21);
    strcpy(temp, "Hello World");
    puts(temp);
    release_ptr(temp);
    return 0;
  default:
    break;
  }
  return -1;
}

int main()
{
  int code;
  scanf("%d", &code);
  printf("%d\n", test(code));
}

In that code, I have a switch statement where I declare a variable inside one of the case labels.    While GCC accepts this code without any issues, Clang produces errors related to undeclared identifiers.
Here is what Clang told to me:
test.c:14:5: error: expected expression
    char* temp = calloc(sizeof(char), 21);
    ^
test.c:15:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'temp'
    strcpy(temp, "Hello World");
           ^
test.c:16:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'temp'
    puts(temp);
         ^
test.c:17:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'temp'
    release_ptr(temp);
                ^
test.c:17:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'temp'
5 errors generated.

The compile instruction I use is: -Og -Wall -Wno-unused-result test.c -o test, for both compilers.
I know enclosing a case statement with curly braces solves this problem, but I still want to know why Clang doesn't accept this and what difference does it make?  Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The code you show does not even contain the lines cited in the error message. Chances are that you forgot to save your code before compiling with either of the compilers.

Anyway, looks like you are compiling different C standard revisions. The one giving you errors seem not to allow variable definitions in the middle of the function.

Sorry but I forgot to change the compilation error message when I changed the code. @EugeneSh.
By the way, I'm using gcc version 13.2.0 and clang version 16.0.6. Both of them use the same compilation options.

I get "source>:14:5: warning: label followed by a declaration is a C23 extension" from clang 18.1.0. This leads to: "Any statement ( but not a declaration ) may be preceded by any number of labels, . . ." (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/statements#Labels)

On my system, gcc 8.3.1 complains about your posted code: char *temp = ... The error is: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement. AFAIK, you can't put a scoped definition inside a case/break block. That is, you can't do: case 1: char *foo = ...; break; To fix this, use braces: case 1: { char *foo = ...; } break; I think that the compiler needs a block to know when foo comes into, and goes out of, scope. It needs the braces to define the scope.

@CraigEstey, you can technically put a variable definition in a case section without {}, just not directly after the case label ( ok in C23). However, it is a bad idea and normally causes other issues. In the OP's case, adding a null statement after the case label would make this work, but I wouldn't recommend that practice. Using braces, as you suggest, I'd consider the right fix.

This discusses the situation in C and C++. It is an issue in both, but in different ways. I'd recomment using braces, as the other approach is more vulnerable to undetected odd things when someone goofs in future code changes.

Try case 1: ; this is how you use a label in MS VC that is not before an executable statement.
